# Change existing sumproduct to have dynamic columns

Tags: excel

I am trying to change my sumproduct so that it will allow for mroe columns to be added. A (shorter) version of what I currently have is

```
SUMPRODUCT((B5:B14+C5:C14+D5:D14)^2)
```

and I want it to go up to any amount of columns starting at B.

Is there anyway to change the equation so that this is possible? Thanks in advance

Comment: So you want B14,C14 and D14 to autmatically change to the last row in which there is a value in column B?

Comment: No, that bit I have working fine (hence why I said shorted version). The data I have won't always end at column D, and so the B4:b14+c4:c14+d4:d14 bit is what I am trying to change as it might need to go all the way to about Z, which is what I want to avoid writing out and forming a stupidly long formula

Comment: then the best method will be to create a helper column that does the addition and square of each row separately then add that column.

Comment: Cheers! That has worked fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All credit for this goes to [Scott Craner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4851590/scott-craner), this is just to mark it as correct. He said

> create a helper column that does the addition and square of each row
>   separately then add that column